# Porque estas Promises de js estan bloqueando la pagina

Tags: javascript, promesas

estaba investigando sobre las `Promise` en js.  Y pretendia hacer la siguiente simulacion:

Empiezo con un flag de estar 'cargando' la pagina (`var loading = true`), **tras 3 s**  una promesa cambiara el flag de carga a `false`. Justo despues de ejecutar esa promesa que cambiara **apagará**
el loader ejecuto otra promesa que estara comprobando cada segundo si ya se **apago el loader** (`loader=false`).

Eso se supone que está haciendo este codigo, o al menos eso creo:

```
var loading = true;



start();

 function start(){
    const milSeconds = 3000;

    //Promete apagar el loader..
    new Promise (()=>{
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Loading off..!');
            loading = !loading;
        }, milSeconds);
    });


    //Promete mostrar un alert cuando el loader este apagado
    new Promise(()=>{
        while(loading){
            console.log('wait..!');
        }

        console.log('La carga ha finalizado!!');
    });


    console.log('Sigue trabajando (hilo main) ..');
}
```

El **problema** es que **la pagina se queda pilalda y ni siquiera carga** . Pero no deberia de ser asi, ya que entiendo que este codigo crea **tres hilos**. El **hilo principal** que realmente no uso para nada mas que crear promesas. **Primera promesa** que apagará el loader. y **Segunda Promesa** que estara pendiente de que ya no este el loader.

**Resultado actual** : La pagina no es capaz de cargar.

## **Ojo:** Antes de probar el codigo guardar lo que esteis haciendo en el navegador, porque se os quedará pillado !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que estás confundiendo las promesas con el trabajo en múltiples hilos. No son lo mismo. Las promesas no inician un hilo nuevo, sino que siguen en el principal. El problema en tu código, es que la segunda promesa está acaparando todos los ciclos de CPU, y ya no se vuelve a la primera para terminarla.

Las promesas permiten tener código asíncrono, pero no necesariamente multi-hilo. Si en tu segunda promesa usas un intervalo, funcionará, porque ya no acaparará toda la CPU.

```js
let loading = true;

function start() {
    const tresSegundos = 3000;

    new Promise(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Loading off');
            loading = false;
        }, tresSegundos);
    });

    let waitInterval = null;
    const medioSegundo = 500;

    new Promise(() => {
        waitInterval = setInterval(() => {
            if (loading) {
                console.log('wait');
            }
            else {
                console.log('fin');
                clearInterval(waitInterval);
            }
        }, medioSegundo);
    });
}

start();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero no termino de entender las promesas entonces.

Comment: @josenangel las promesas permiten manejar código asíncrono, sin embargo estas no "crean" ni destruyen hilos, ya que en javascript, por lo menos el nativo del navegador estás limitado a siempre estar usando un solo hilo, independientemente de cuántos hilos tenga tu procesador, esto debido a que javascript es un lenguaje de programación monohilo, por lo que en el el concepto de threads no se puede manejar múltiples hilos, así los tengas disponibles.